# While loop and If condition does not work with append to?

Tags: list-manipulation

when i try to append values using do loop and if condition i can store all the values like below.

```
datax1 = {};

nl = 0.0; h = 0.007;

Do[If[t == nl*h, AppendTo[datax1, {t, 2}]; nl = nl + 10 ], {t, 0.0, 1.0,h}];

Length[datax1]

143
```

but when i use the same conditions in while loop i can store only less values using append to why ?

```
t = 0.0; nl = 0.0; h = 0.0007;datax2 = {};

While[t <= 1.0, If[t == nl*h, AppendTo[datax2, {t, 2}]; nl = nl + 10]; t = t + h]

 Length[datax2]

127
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this

Comment: @Bill Thanks for your reply, i have re edited the code and i have checked it but still i got the same result. I dont know why appendTo  stores less values in while loop when we are using if condition.

Comment: Why not just use something like `Table[{i, 2}, {i, 0., 1, .07}]`? Similar to list comprehensions, if one must recall some counterpart.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes. The reason for the difference appears to be how Mathematica deals with numbers containing decimal points. If you change all your numbers to exact integers or exact rationals with no decimal points then both blocks of code return 15. Once you have that out of the way then you might explore exactly what those extra steps are doing. You can use `FullForm` on a decimal value to see more than the usual half dozen digits that are displayed.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ thanks for the reply. Actually i want to store some points in the code using if condition .The table function stores all points. Can i know how your idea works? Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest `Sow` and `Reap`.

Comment: Or maybe you can select "valid" iterators by your conditions first, and then use `Table`.

Comment: @Bill can you please post your code with your idea i dont find any change in the result if i try it.Thanks in advance

Comment: `datax1={}; nl=0; h=7/1000; Do[If[t==nl*h, AppendTo[datax1,{t,2}]; nl=nl+10], {t,0,1,h}]; Length[datax1]` and `t=0; nl=0; h=7/1000; datax2={}; While[t<=1, If[t==nl*h, AppendTo[datax2,{t,2}]; nl=nl+10]; t=t+h]; Length[datax2]` both return 15. Compare those datax1 and datax2 with your original datax1 and datax2 and then use FullForm on each of them. Perhaps that will uncover the issues with decimal points. Perhaps not.

Comment: @Bill Thank you very much sir for the help it worked fine for my problem